# Show message when unchecking everything and show other message every time I mark each check

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How can I make a message appear when I uncheck all the checks and while it is marked one or more check shows another message

```
<label for="1">Checkbox 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="1" value="1">
<label for="2">Checkbox 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="2" value="2">
<label for="3">Checkbox 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" name="3" value="3">
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("input[type="checkbox"]:checked").each(function() {
             alert('check');
        });
       
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following function to do the job:

(if all checkboxes are UNCHECKED, it shows a different message, else show a simple message)

```js
    function Validate() {
        var checked = 0;
 
        //Reference the Table.
        var tblFruits = document.getElementById("tblFruits");
 
        //Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
        var chks = tblFruits.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
 
        //Loop and count the number of checked CheckBoxes.
        for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
            if (chks[i].checked) {
                checked++;
            }
        }
 
        if (checked ==0) {
            alert("ALL CheckBoxes are UNCHECKED !");
        } else {
            alert("You have checked one or more checkboxes");
        }
    };
```

```html
<div id="tblFruits">
<label for="1">Checkbox 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" onclick = "return Validate()" name="1" value="1">
<label for="2">Checkbox 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check"onclick = "return Validate()"  name="2" value="2">
<label for="3">Checkbox 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" onclick = "return Validate()" name="3" value="3">  
    
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply checked if the `length` of `checked` checkboxes are greater `0` then show some message else show `"no checkbox checked"` message.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".check").change(function() {
//get length of checked checkboxes
  var message = $(".somediv input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0 ? "More then 1 checkbox is checked" : "No checkbox is checked";
  console.log(message)

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="somediv">
  <label for="1">Checkbox 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="1" value="1">
  <label for="2">Checkbox 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="2" value="2">
  <label for="3">Checkbox 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="3" value="3">
</div>
```